# Is there an easy to use PHP PDF library with unicode support?

Tags: php, pdf, unicode, pdf-generation

I tried `dompdf`. It's a lot easier to use than other libraries I've tried but it doesn't have unicode support. Or rather, it has unicode support but requires another library called `PDFLib` ($1k version).

So I am just wondering if anybody has ever stumbled upon or used any PHP pdf library which is both easy to use *and* has unicode support.

Comment: Removing the ". anybody??" would make your question appear less rude.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[I think fpdf supports that.](http://www.fpdf.org/phorum/read.php?f=1&i=5142&t=5142)**

Comment: i was looking for something similar to dom pdf.
thnx

Comment: it is not converting HTML to PDF. just text to PDF

Answer (score 2):

You can use TCPDF:
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_008.pdf
http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_018.pdf

or you can use html2pdf - it's using tcpdf at its core but it's made to particularly convert html to pdf (css..):
Html2pdf
http://demo.html2pdf.fr/examples/pdf/utf8.pdf

and last but not least: mpdf
http://www.mpdf1.com/mpdf/index.php

maight be fastest and make smallest pdf in size ( then other two ). also has font_autodetect to detect and use unicode fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, fpdf supports it. I have used it to generate documents in various Indian languages.

Comment: i was looking for something similar to dom pdf. thnx

Answer (score 0):

The 0.6.0 release of DOMPDF will fully support Unicode. This version is currently in beta, but it's worth a try.